# Will Apple reject using Realm with Swift as it uses private APIs for reflection?

Tags: appstore-approval, realm, iphone-privateapi

Realm uses reflection to build DB from Swift models. Everything was fine for Objective C. But Swift doesn't support reflection for public use. They used private API for that reason, the same way as XCode use this API for inspecting variables during debug process. This fact means that Apple could reject application from AppStore. Has anyone had an issue?

Answer (score 4):

Swift's reflection API actually is public -- it's exposed directly by the Swift standard library modules, and we've heard zero issues about its use from developers deploying to the app store.